# Как в шаблоне django вывести тегом цикла FOR определенный диапазон?

Tags: django, шаблоны

В article находится список статей. В определенном месте мне нужно вывести, допустим, статьи с 3 по 10. Можно ли как то указать этот диапазон при использовании тега цикла for ?

```
{% for article in lastarticles %}
<div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class = "thumbnail ">
     <img src = "{{ article.main_image.url }}">
  </div>
```

```
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно так и можно сделать, но это не правильно. Джанго построен на паттерне MVC. Паттерн разделяет отображение и контроллер.

Поэтому язык шаблонов, джанговский, создавался не для программирования, а для построения страниц. Вся логика должна располагаться в отображениях(вьюхах).

То есть срез вы должны сделать во вьюхе, и передать циклу уже готовый список.

**По ответу на вопрос.**
Возможно и прокатит такой ход, не проверял:

```
{% for article in lastarticles|slice:"3:10" %}
    ...

{% endfor %}
```

Но вы всё равно не сможете изменять параметры среза, потому как язык шаблонов джанги не поддерживает объявление переменных.

Если же хотите не смотря ни на что программировать на языке шаблонов, то можно использовать Jinja2.

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, range() не поддерживается языком шаблонов Django(не уверен на счет новых версий). Поэтому могу только предложить вариант делить на нужные тебе диапазоны еще во вьюшке и передавать диапазоны в контексте.

Для строк, кстати, есть фильтр slice. Вырезает нужный объем строки:
{{ obj.name|slice:"0:3" }}